# How to display mysql results in separate unordered lists by alphabet

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a webpage that queries a list of links to subpages. The subpages are divided by alphabet, and formatted as dynamic nested unordered lists with each letter of the alphabet having its own heading. I currently have it working, but with 26 separate queries. I'd like to do the same thing, but with only 1 query instead of 26. Here's a snippet of what I have now, showing just letters A and B. I'm fairly new to PHP, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I've looked extensively, but haven't found any answers that allow for the nested unordered list formatting, or anything remotely similar.

```
<ul class="navMenu">
<?php
$servername = "XXX";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM addsor WHERE title LIKE 'A%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<li class='navMenuItem'>A";
  echo "<ul class='navSubMenu'>";
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $title = $row["title"];
    $linkname = $row["linkname"];
    echo "<li class='navSubMenuItem'><a href='addsor_result.php?sortitle=$linkname' onclick='popsor(this.href); return false;'>$title</a></li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
  echo "</li>";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addsor WHERE title LIKE 'B%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<li class='navMenuItem'>B";
  echo "<ul class='navSubMenu'>";
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $title = $row["title"];
    $linkname = $row["linkname"];
    echo "<li class='navSubMenuItem'><a href='addsor_result.php?sortitle=$linkname' onclick='popsor(this.href); return false;'>$title</a></li>";
  };
  echo "</ul>";
  echo "</li>";
};
?>
</ul>
```

Per Jerson, I edited the code to use an if statement:

```
<ul class="navMenu">
<?php
$servername = "XXX";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM addsor";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $find = substr($row["title"], 0, 1);
    $title = $row["title"];
    $linkname = $row["linkname"];
    if ($find === "A") {
      echo "<li class='navMenuItem menu-header'>A";
      echo "<ul class='navSubMenu'>";
      echo "<li class='navSubMenuItem'><a href='addsor_result.php?sortitle=$linkname' onclick='popsor(this.href); return false;'>$title</a></li>\r\n";
      echo "</ul>";
      echo "</li>";
    }
    elseif ($find === "B") {
      echo "<li class='navMenuItem menu-header'>B";
      echo "<ul class='navSubMenu'>";
      echo "<li class='navSubMenuItem'><a href='addsor_result.php?sortitle=$linkname' onclick='popsor(this.href); return false;'>$title</a></li>";
      echo "</ul>";
      echo "</li>";
    }
  };
};
</ul>
```

But now, instead of being grouped like:
**A**
      Aaa
      Aab
      Aac
**B**
      Baa
      Bab
      Bac
etc.

they're appearing like:

**A**
      Aaa
**A**
      Aab
**A**
      Aac
**B**
      Baa
**B**
      Bab
etc.

Comment: ... this should be one query - the page load bottle neck is connection to the database, and you repeat this 26 times for one `nav`... MySql has good https://www.mysqltutorial.org/ read it, please. Don't kill the server `select * from addsor order by title` possibly with `collate`

Comment: What you want, is a simple one-level _control break_. Your data needs to be properly sorted to begin with, and then while you loop over it, you compare the value of the relevant criterion, to that of the previous record you processed - based on whether they are the same, or different, you react accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different approach, and got the results I was looking for. Thanks to all those that offered assistance. Here's the new code:

```
<ul class="navMenu">
<?php
$servername = "XXX";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM addsor";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$firstletter = "";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $title = $row["title"];
    $linkname = $row["linkname"];
    if (substr($row["title"], 0, 1) !== $firstletter) {
      if (!empty($firstletter)) {echo "</li></ul>";}
      $firstletter = substr($row["title"], 0, 1);
      echo "<li class='navMenuItem'>".$firstletter."<ul class='navSubMenu'>";
    }
    echo "<li class='navSubMenuItem'><a href='addsor_result.php?sortitle=$linkname' onclick='popsor(this.href); return false;'>$title</a></li>\r\n";
  };
};
$conn->close();
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using if statement instead of repeating query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addsor";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $find = substr( $row["title"], 0, 1 );

        if($find === "A") {
            
            // add your code here
        }
        
    };
};
```

my test example

```
$arr = ["Aaa","Aab","Aac","Baa","Bab","Bac"];

foreach($arr as $val) {
 $find = substr($val, 0, 1);

 if($find == "A") {
  echo $val . "\r\n";
 } elseif($find == "B") {
  echo $val . "\r\n";
 }

}
```

i got following result

```
 run-project -l php
Aaa
Aab
Aac
Baa
Bab
Bac

```

Comment: That sort of works for me. The problem is that each item is getting it's own heading. So if I have 25 items that start with A, it's showing 25 separate lists of 1 item each nested under its own heading. I want the letter heading to appear once before each list of nested items.

Comment: hello can i see  your data , its working here , here is my test array ["Aaa","Aab","Aac","Baa","Bab","Bac"]

Comment: added example with using foreach